# how to configure jenkins to work with websvn

Tags: hudson, jenkins, websvn

I started using jenkins and now trying to configure it to use websvn for diff and files view. I saw a [post](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/WebSVN-links-td388400.html) that say I have to configure multyviews. but I dont understand exactly what it means and how to work with it after it is configured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to use websvn2 plugin of jenkins which support the url with parameters

Comment: [The WebSVN2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSVN2+Plugin) referred to in oshai's solution.

Comment: Once the WebSVN2 Plugin is installed, select "WebSVN2" as the repository browser rather than "WebSVN".